# iOs 15.1 - Performance issue with array filtering using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, nspredicate, ios15

We have an iPhone app where we are extensively using NSPredicate for array filtering. With iOS 15.1 upgrade, we started seeing performance issues with our app. After troubleshooting, we found slowness with array filtering, which otherwise works pretty fast on iOS 15.0.2 and below versions.

Has anyone else faced such issue? If so, any resolution available? We couldn't find anything in release notes for iOS 15.1, which could cause this issue.

**Update - Added sample code**

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“ID = %@“, value];
NSMutableArray *result = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Here, data is of type NSArray.

Comment: Show some minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @DonMag updated with sample code.

Comment: Swift and filter without using predicates would be a lot faster.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes we eventually did that. But I wonder what changed in iOS 15.1 that the performance difference is so huge.

Comment: @VaibhavBansal - I meant, **complete** minimal code, so we could copy/paste and run some testing. See [mre].